# How to correctly recall directory variables with space in its path in BASH

Tags: bash

I need to run a bash script to copy a list of files to my phone.

This was a test run that worked:

```
cp f.jpg /home/ariela/phone/Internal\ storage/Pictures/Test
```

I want the directory to be a variable. So I tried this:

```
DEST="/home/ariela/phone/Internal\ storage/Pictures/Test"
cp f.jpg $DEST
```

And it did not work because it recognizes storage/Pictures/Test as second parameter and not part of the path.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside quotes no need to escape the space but make sure to **quote it in `cp` command**.

You can use:

```
phonedir='/home/ariela/phone/Internal storage/Pictures/Test'

cp f.jpg "$phonedir"
```